# Word for not knowing if something is good or bad?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So I'm trying to find a word for if you are unsure whether something could be good or could be bad. The context I'm using it in is that a character noticed something about themselves that they are unsure whether it is a good or bad thing. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write an example sentence in which the word you are looking for could be used? It could help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the character is [*ambivalent*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalent?s=ts), or has *mixed feelings*, or is *of two minds* about what they have observed.